# Print regex matches in java

Tags: java, regex

So I have an IP address as a string.
I have this regex `(\d{1-3})\.(\d{1-3})\.(\d{1-3})\.(\d{1-3})`
How do I print the matching groups?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
import java.util.regex.*;
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(\\d\\{1-3\\})\\.(\\d\\{1-3\\})\\.(\\d\\{1-3\\})\\.(\\d\\{1-3\\})");
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= regexMatcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            // matched text: regexMatcher.group(i)
            // match start: regexMatcher.start(i)
            // match end: regexMatcher.end(i)
        }
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to catch PatternSyntaxException if your regex is hardcoded (like it is). If there's an error in the syntax, you'll find it the first time you run the program.

Comment: Shouldn't the counter begin on 0?

Answer (score 6):

If you use Pattern and Matcher to do your regex, then you can ask the Matcher for each group using the [group(int group)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int)) method

So:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{1-3}).(\\d{1-3}).(\\d{1-3}).(\\d{1-3})"); 
Matcher m = p.matcher("127.0.0.1"); 
if (m.matches()) {   
  System.out.print(m.group(1));  
  // m.group(0) is the entire matched item, not the first group.
  // etc... 
}
```