# Print out the string that matched my regular expression in java?

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

**Possible duplicate:** [Print regex matches in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836704/print-regex-matches-in-java)

I am using Matcher class in java to match a string with a particular regular expression which I converted into a Pattern using the Pattern class. I know my regex works because when I do Matcher.find(), I am getting true values where I am supposed to. But I want to print out the stings that are producing those true values (meaning print out the strings that match my regex) and I don't see a method in the matcher class to achieve that. Please do let me know if anyone has encountered such a problem before. I apologize as this question is fairly rudimentary but I am fairly new to regex and hence am still finding my way around the regex world.

Comment: See this question, you will find out some good solutions here...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/836704/print-regex-matches-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `m`is your matcher:

`m.group()` will return the matched string.

**[EDIT]** Added info regarding matched groups

Also, if your regex has portions inside parenthesis, `m.group(n)` will return the string that matches the nth group inside parenthesis;

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("mary (.*) bob");
Matcher m = p.matcher("since that day mary loves bob");
```

`m.group()` returns "mary loves bob".
`m.group(1)` return "loves".

Comment: thank you I just figured it out. The group() method name was kind of throwing me off I guess. Doesn't seem intuitive I don't know why they didn't have a more descriptive name for it.

Comment: I've edited my answer, explaning what `groups` really are.  Once you're familiar with regex's groups, it does make sense (I do admit I used regexes for years before I understood that though).