# regular expression in java compile

Tags: regex

this is my regular expression, which I use on command line, but when I put the same expressing on java pattern.compile, it is giving an error

This is my regex  `/,.*"(.*)",\[6]/`

This is how I am trying in java

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/,.*"(.*)",\[6]/");
```

but in eclipse it is showing an error, could some one help on this.

Comment: Don't the quotes make it obvious that it'd be an error?

Comment: What is the pattern you are trying to match?

Comment: This is the string ]],,[,"good",[6]], I am trying to get that 'good' The string is big, But I posted only the important part of that string

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the double quotes (and possibly the blackslash) using backslashes.

EDIT:

It seems what you want is this

```
,.*\"(.+)\",\\[6\\]
```

You don't have to include forward slashes in patterns in Java. If you know you will have something between quotes, use `+` instead of `*`, and you have to escape the square brackets, because you want a literal match.

Comment: I did that, still it give an error Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/,.*\"(.*)\",\[6]/");

Comment: Hi, this is how I used in php  preg_match( '/,.*"(.*)",\[6]/', $res, $match ); which worked fine for me can you let me know how do I use in java to match the same

Comment: No, it says no match found ava.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found

Comment: String input = inputLine;
             System.out.println(input);
             
             Pattern p = Pattern.compile(",.*\"(.+)\",\\[6\\]");
             Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
             System.out.println(m);
             String match = m.group(1);
             System.out.println("This is the pattern-->" +match); Here the input string will be [[["మంచి","good","Man̄ci","Good"]],,"hi",,[["మంచి",[1],true,false,1000,0,1,0]],[["good",1,[["మంచి",1000,true,false],["గుడ్",0,true,false],["మంచిది",0,true,false],["బాగుంది",0,true,false]],[[0,4]],"good"]],,[,"गुड",[6]],[["en"]],7]

Comment: I want to get the hindi word in that string

Comment: You forgot to call `m.find()` before calling `m.group(1)`

Comment: Ohh, thank you very much, it worked for me, I took the sample code from stack overflow itself but it does not contain m.find so I have not included that. Thanks again. Here I took the sample code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910834/print-out-the-string-that-matched-my-regular-expression-in-java